# Getting videos from Assets catalog using On Demand resources

Tags: xcode7, ios9, asset-catalog, on-demand-resources

I attributed the tag "tokyo" to my .mp4 video, and set it as installed during the app installation.

Originally, I was using a path to load it from my resources, however, now it's different because it's located in the Asset catalog.

After reading the documentation, I tried something like:

```
NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: ["tokyo"]).beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
    let tokyoVideo = NSDataAsset(name: "tokyo")
}
```

To access this video as NSData I could use:

```
tokyoVideo.data
```

However, I'm using AVPlayer which takes the parameter as an NSURL, not NSData.

So how do I get the NSURL for my video?
Is the Asset catalog only for storing Data and should I be using that to store my video, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its possible to use Asset Catalog for video stuff, Its simplify management of images. Use NSDataAsset for it. Review the last row in below table.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH2-SW1) for more info

The following table lists the types of resources that can be tagged as on-demand resources.

[image]

Comment: Ho I just saw https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Chapters/ODRTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH9-SW1

Yes, it can't be on the asset catalog..  ^^

Comment: Note the "data file" line in the table, though. If you create a "Data Set" in your assets catalog in Xcode, you can stick device-specific videos in it and  use the `NSDataAsset` class to load them at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is putting the mp4 in the asset catalogue. Resources don't have to be in the asset catalogue to be accessed as on demand resources.

Move your assets out of the catalogue in to the workspace and tag them then use the bundle property of the NSBundleResourceRequest

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var bundleRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let tags: Set<String>  = ["odr"]
        bundleRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: tags)

        bundleRequest.beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler { (error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if let e = error {
                print(e)
                return
            }
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                if let url = self.bundleRequest.bundle.URLForResource("tokyo", withExtension: "mp4") {
                    //use the url to play the video with avplayer
                }

            })
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for noting that nsbundleresourcerequest object has "bundle" property.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can the movie will end up getting stored in a data file.

NSDataAsset

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.